# Как сделать отклик спрайта на касание курсором мыши

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

Допустим я хочу сделать кнопку которая будет увеличиваться при наведении на неё курсором, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отслеживаете когда координаты курсора мыши будут в квадрате кнопки, событие  pygame.MOUSEMOTION, координаты мыши в event.pos. Затем, с помощью pygame.transform.scale() или медленно - pygame.transform.smoothscale() меняете размер кнопки, если кнопка - изображение. Смотри видео: https://www.yewtu.be/watch?v=-AbhthvOVts&nojs=1